# Sas sgplot wrong order of x-axis labels and data

Tags: sas

a very simple question...
I'm trying to plot some data with sgplot. On the x-axis I should have: t0, t6, t12, t18 but sas orders as follows: t0, t12, t18, t6.
I tried to manually set the desired order and I also tried to sort the data by the column containing t* labels following the desired order but nothing happens. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you please show your sgplot-code?

Comment: Instead of T0 to T18 use the numerics, 0 to 18 and apply a format or use T00 T01 T09 and it will sort correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `xaxis values=` statement to specify your order. For example:

```
data have;
    input t$ value;
    datalines;
t0 1
t12 10
t18 30
t6 4
;
run;

proc sgplot data=have;
    vbar t / response=value;
    xaxis values=('t0' 't6' 't12' 't18');
run;
```

[image]

If you have a lot of these, you can read the order all into a macro variable by extracting the numeric part of each value of `t`, then convert it to a numeric variable for sorting.

```
data set_order;
    set have;

    /* Get only the numeric part */
    t_order = input(compress(t,,'A'), 8.);
run;

proc sort data=set_order;
    by t_order;
run;

proc sql noprint;
    select quote(t)
    into :t separated by ' '
    from set_order;
quit;

proc sgplot data=have;
    vbar t / response=value;
    xaxis values=(&t.);
run;
```